# Python Crash Course 8-15, Not Defined Error

Tags: python

I'm reading the book 'Python Crash Course' by Eric Matthes and I seem to be having issues with exercise 8-15.

8-15 says: "Put the functions for the example print_models.py in a separate file called printing_functions.py. Write an import statement at the top of print_models.py, and modify the file to use the imported functions.

**Here is my code for the printing_functions.py module:**

```
def print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models):
    """Simulate printing each design, until none are left.
    Move each design to completed_models after printing."""
    while unprinted_designs:
        current_design = unprinted_designs.pop()

        # Simulate creating a 3D print from the design.
        print("Printing model: " + current_design)
        completed_models.append(current_design)

def show_completed_models(completed_models):
    """Show all the models that were printed."""
    print("\nThe following models have been printed:")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)

unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []
print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

**Here is my code for exercise 8-15**

```
import printing_functions as pf

pf.print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
pf.show_completed_models(completed_models)

unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []
print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

When I run this code, I'm able to receive the same output as in the module. However I also receive and error at the bottom stating that 'unprinted_designs' is not defined. But I clearly have this variable defined near the bottom of my code as a list so I do not understand why I am getting this error.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you have extraneous code in `print_functions.py`? Get rid of the code not in a function because it's an exact copy. Define your variables before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

You've mostly done the correct thing, but variables need to be assigned before you can use them.

Also, since you've separated / moved the functions to a module, you have to use those imported ones while the variables remain in this module

```
import printing_functions as pf

unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []

pf.print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
pf.show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

Then, remove the unnecessary lines at the end of the other module. Only the function definitions should be there

Comment: Thank you for your comment, when I do this though, my answer is printed twice though. I tried removing the bottom lines in the module but it didn't do anything.

Comment: It's printed twice because at the bottom of `printing_functions.py`, you are running those functions